# SQL Increment Counter

Tags: sql-server, counter, increment

I have a column which has values like

```
2014.STA.?
2014.STA.?
2014.STA.?
2015.STA.?
2016.STA.?
2014.STA.?
2014.STA.?
2016.STA.?
```

I need to create a function that I can group by year and add the index instead of "?". It means, I want to get a result like that

```
2014.STA.1
2014.STA.2
2014.STA.3
2015.STA.1
2016.STA.1
2014.STA.4
2014.STA.5
2016.STA.2
```

I dont know how to grup these column and use it in a function.

for mssql2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select substring(c1, 1, 9) + CONVERT(CHAR, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by c1 ORDER BY substring(c1,1,4)))  from @tabla
```

It works on my SQL Server 2014. Check this:

```
select substring(c1, 1, 9) + cast(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by c1 ORDER BY substring(c1,1,4)) as char(12))  from @tabla
```

If yoy want to order by the number:

```
select r1 from (
select substring(c1, 1, 9) + cast(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by c1 ORDER BY substring(c1,1,4)) as char(12)) AS r1 from @tabla) AS T
order by substring(r1, 10, len(r1))
```

Comment: your code works a bit different.. I have these result

Comment: 2014.STA.124                           
2014.STA.125                           
2014.STA.72                            
2015.STA.12                            
2016.STA.64                            
2014.STA.295                           
2014.STA.105                           
2016.STA.65                            
2014.STA.182

Comment: it does not start from 1 ... the first number is 124

Comment: I checked all values are right.. Only problem is order.. How can start from 1 ? any idea

Answer (score 3):

Use `Row_Number` window function to generate the numbers

```
select left(yourcol,len(yourcol)-1)+cast(RN as varchar(20)) 
(
select row_number()over(partition by your_col order yourcol) As RN,*
From yourtable
)
```

Comment: i could not implement your code.. it gives many error.. I have a complex query and difficult to implement this

Answer (score 3):

I think this does what you want:

```
select (left(col, 9) +
        cast(row_number() over (partition by left(col, 9) order by (select null)) as varchar(255))
       )
```

Note:  This puts an arbitrary ordering on the values.  Presumably, there is a column that specifies the proper ordering of the numbers.

Actually, you can do this without the `cast()` by using `replace()`:

```
select replace(col, '?', 
               row_number() over (partition by left(col, 9) order by (select NULL))
              )
```

The `cast()` is implicit in this version.

Comment: thank you for your reply, the first code has problem with as varchar(255).. and for the second code, The ranking function "row_number" must have an ORDER BY clause. error

Comment: and i think this code does not groupping by date? I need to group by date. If you see the first message, you will see that it is grupped by year